# resolution QIcon in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, icons, resolution

I'm making GUI an ImageViewer Application, but despite I'm using 512x512 resolution icons, they all appear with low resolution.

[image: 1]

```
self.left_rotate = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.left_rotate.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
self.left_rotate.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
self.left_rotate.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
self.left_rotate.setText("")
self.left_rotate.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(16, 16))
self.left_rotate.setObjectName("left_rotate")
self.tool_bar.addWidget(self.left_rotate)
```

This is the code generated by QTCreator.
I tried to increase "Icon Size" value, but I don't want that the button gets bigger than now.

Comment: How are you setting the icons? And in what format are they?

Comment: self.ui.right_rotate.setIcon(QIcon("icons/rotate_right.png"))

Answer (score 1):

Add this line after instantiating the QApplication: `app.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)`